# Кальмиусский (район)

Tags: грамотная-речь, акцентология

С каким ударением произносится слово Кальмиусский?

Answer (score 2):

А вопрос-то непростой. По-украински - Кальміу́ський.

Но, думаю, по-русски - Ка́льмиусский.

Вообще-то такие вещи надо только по словарю проверять. Но здесь уникальное название - в смысле единственное на всем земном шаре. Речка Ка́льмиус (на обоих языках), тут сомнений нет, бывает, что ударение смещается в производных словах и формах, но тут причин нет, если оставаться в рамках русской фонологии.

А вот в украинском, такое смещение ударения на конец корня перед "ськiй" - дело довольно обычное (влияние польского, что ли?). Отсюда и разночтения.

Comment: Может ли в слове из 4 слогов ударение падать на первый?

Comment: @М_Г   (O_o) вам на вес? масленица, иконопись, милостивый, оборотень... Из пяти хотите? выхолощенный... Это только то, что сразу на ум пришло. Зализняк, помнится, приводил из восьми(!) слогов с первым ударным - ходовое, совсем не из параллельной реальности... Вот вспомнить не могу. А уж на ский:  -ский: кайзеровский, кавголовский, байеровский... - врот как раз у таких иноязычных основ, особенно - имен собственных, и не смещается обычно ударение в производных словах и формах.

Answer (score 1):

**[Словарь трудностей произношения и ударения в современном русском языке](https://books.google.ru/books?id=2ZnOAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA169&lpg=PA169&dq=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=xvQpsMAjdO&sig=Huzg21K1bEJAe4iWkKBtDI4xe5E&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn_sH80p_aAhUIjiwKHazFD1MQ6AEISzAE#v=onepage&q&f=false)**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По прецеденту - Кальмиу́сский район.